# Directly proportional Trend in training and cross validation curves

Tags: machine-learning, data, cross-validation, accuracy

In continuation with a [question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/14220/training-and-cross-validation-error-curves) already asked, I tried the same curve on a different dataset I found. My model is a simple Logistic regression curve with OnevsRest Classifier. But the graph I obtained this time was different.
[image]

What could be a possible reason for this? As explained in the other answer, if it takes less data to fit better, shouldn't the accuracy decrease here as well?

Comment: I think this is unusual. I have a suspection though - could you try to randomly shuffle your data (X and y) and check if you're still getting the same learning curve when you use the shuffled data?

Comment: I used sklearn's learning_curve to do this. sklearn does actually randomly shuffle internally while plotting this curve.

Comment: PS.: with shuffling X and y I don't mean to use KFold(..., shuffle=True), but something like permutation = np.random.permutation(len(X)), X = X[permutation], y = y[permutation]. Let me know if that changes your learning curve.

Comment: I don't think it does - I get very different results when I shuffle or not. Please try shuffling it yourself with np.random.permutation as explained above.

Answer (score 1):

These learning curves seem unusual - the training accuracy should start high and get lower as more samples are added.

I suspect that your data is sequential (it has some kind of time dependency). sklearn's learning_curve function does not seem to shuffle the data (should it?), so the training accuracy can change/increase once new structures appear in the data over time.

Here's a notebook trying to reproduce the effect:
https://gist.github.com/stmax82/79b744877b0a482f8739d372c4777e0d

Two images from the notebook:

The learning curves on the **shuffled data** look like that (as expected):

[image: learning curves on shuffled data]

While the learning curves on the **original / sequential data** look like that (unusual because training accuracy is rising over time):

[image: learning curves on original data]

That's just my try at explaining your learning curves. It might be something completely different... try shuffling your data to find out.

Comment: I shuffled the dataset and tried it again as you suggested. It seems to follow the same trend.

Comment: Alright. I guess we need a new hypothesis then :p

Comment: It may be useful to have a pointer to the data